# How can I annotate types for a pluggy hook specification?

Tags: python, mypy

I'd like to add type annotations to my pluggy hook specifications so that hook implementations can be type checked. Using this simplified example from the [pluggy documentation](https://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import pluggy  # type: ignore

hookspec = pluggy.HookspecMarker("myproject")
hookimpl = pluggy.HookimplMarker("myproject")


class MySpec(object):
    """A hook specification namespace."""

    @hookspec
    def myhook(self, arg1, arg2):
        """My special little hook that you can customize."""


class Plugin_1(object):
    """A hook implementation namespace."""

    @hookimpl
    def myhook(self, arg1, arg2):
        print("inside Plugin_1.myhook()")
        return arg1 + arg2 + "a" # intentional error


# create a manager and add the spec
pm = pluggy.PluginManager("myproject")
pm.add_hookspecs(MySpec)
# register plugins
pm.register(Plugin_1())
# call our `myhook` hook
# intentional incompatible type for parameter arg2
results = pm.hook.myhook(arg1=1, arg2="1")
print(results)
```

I believe the correct effective annotation would be:

```
def myhook(self, arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int: ...
```

I tried adding this annotation to the hookspec. As I expected this doesn't work. I believe this is because the indirection implemented by pluggy is dynamic. The code must be run so that the `add_hookspecs()` method of `PluginManager` can define the available hook.

I see that `pm.hook` is of the type `pluggy.hooks._HookRelay` and `pm.hook.myhook` is an instance of `pluggy.hooks._HookCaller` which has a `__call__()` method.

I tried using `stubgen` to make a set of `.pyi` files for pluggy and then adding the annotation to `pluggy.hooks._HookCaller` in two different ways:

```
class _HookCaller:
    def __init__(self, trace: Any) -> None: ...
    def myhook(self, arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int: ...
    def __call__(self, arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int: ...
```

When I execute `MYPYPATH=./stubs mypy --verboes example.py` I can see `hooks.pyi` being parsed but the argument type mismatch is not detected. This behavior is consistent even if I remove the `# type: ignore` annotation from `import pluggy`.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to define, as an external `.pyi` file, the type annotations for the `myhook()` hook?
2. If so, what would that `.pyi` file contain and where do I store it so that `mypy` picks it up when type checking is run?
3. Is it possible to annotate such that both the hook implementer and the hook caller get useful type hints?

Comment: I'm looking at mypy plugins now, perhaps I need a plugin that returns the type annotations for `_HookCaller`'s `__call__` method dynamically? I'm unclear how this would work but I'm noodling around on it.

Comment: Answer to ^: After the plugin is registered I can then `cast()` it to add a runtime type hint: `pm.hook = cast(MySpecAnnotated, pm.hook)`. `MySpecAnnotated` is a stub version of `MySpec` with the `@hookspec` decorator removed. `@hookspec` drops the type annotations. If I could figure out how to mangle `@hookspec` so that it passed the type annotations through this would work!

Comment: Both question and answer are excellent - I'm in need of `pluggy` typings too, because without them it's impossible to properly type anything `pytest` related. Leaving a link to [issue #191](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy/issues/191) here too, for the sake of completeness (I guess you're the author of it, too). Thanks for the suggested workaround until the type hints actually arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that `@hookspec` obliterates the type hints for the `myhook` method:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any, cast

# Improvement suggested by @oremanj on python/typing gitter
F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[..., Any])
hookspec = cast(Callable[[F], F], pluggy.HookspecMarker("myproject"))
```

That workaround negates the requirement for an external `.pyi` file. Just use the existing hook specification to define the type hints. This addresses Q1 and Q2: You don't need a `.pyi` file. Just use `typing.cast()` to give mypy a hint that it can't learn from static analysis:

```
# Add cast so that mypy knows that pm.hook
# is actually a MySpec instance. Without this
# hint there really is no way for mypy to know
# this.
pm.hook = cast(MySpec, pm.hook)
```

This can be checked by adding annotations:

```
# Uncomment these when running through mypy to see
# how mypy regards the type
reveal_type(pm.hook)
reveal_type(pm.hook.myhook)
reveal_type(MySpec.myhook)
```

Run this through mypy:

```
plug.py:24: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
plug.py:42: error: Revealed type is 'plug.MySpec'
plug.py:43: error: Revealed type is 'def (arg1: builtins.int, arg2: builtins.int) -> builtins.int'
plug.py:44: error: Revealed type is 'def (self: plug.MySpec, arg1: builtins.int, arg2: builtins.int) -> builtins.int'
plug.py:47: error: Argument "arg2" to "myhook" of "MySpec" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

Now `mypy` catches the type issues on both the hook caller and hook implementation (Q3)!

Full code:

```
import pluggy  # type: ignore
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any, cast

# Improvement suggested by @oremanj on python/typing gitter
F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[..., Any])
hookspec = cast(Callable[[F], F], pluggy.HookspecMarker("myproject"))
hookimpl = pluggy.HookimplMarker("myproject")


class MySpec(object):
    """A hook specification namespace."""

    @hookspec
    def myhook(self, arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int:
        """My special little hook that you can customize."""


class Plugin_1(object):
    """A hook implementation namespace."""

    @hookimpl
    def myhook(self, arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int:
        print("inside Plugin_1.myhook()")
        return arg1 + arg2 + 'a'


# create a manager and add the spec
pm = pluggy.PluginManager("myproject")
pm.add_hookspecs(MySpec)

# register plugins
pm.register(Plugin_1())

# Add cast so that mypy knows that pm.hook
# is actually a MySpec instance. Without this
# hint there really is no way for mypy to know
# this.
pm.hook = cast(MySpec, pm.hook)

# Uncomment these when running through mypy to see
# how mypy regards the type
# reveal_type(pm.hook)
# reveal_type(pm.hook.myhook)
# reveal_type(MySpec.myhook)

# this will now be caught by mypy
results = pm.hook.myhook(arg1=1, arg2="1")
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of things in the answer by Brad can be done in a pluggy.pyi file. I have this (probably very incomplete) content of pluggy.pyi:

```py
from types import ModuleType
from typing import Callable, Type, TypeVar, Generic, Any


F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[..., Any])


class HookspecMarker:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        ...

    def __call__(self, func: F) -> F:
        ...


class HookimplMarker:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        ...

    def __call__(self, func: F) -> F:
        ...


Spec = TypeVar("Spec")


class PluginManager(Generic[Spec]):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        ...

    def load_setuptools_entrypoints(self, name: str) -> None:
        ...

    def add_hookspecs(self, module: Type[Spec]) -> None:
        ...

    def register(self, module: ModuleType) -> None:
        ...

    hook: Spec
```

This allows me to create a plugin manager as follows:

```py
import pluggy
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from .hookspecs import PluginSpec
from .plugins import localplugins


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    PluginManager = pluggy.PluginManager[PluginSpec]
else:
    PluginManager = pluggy.PluginManager

plugin: PluginManager = pluggy.PluginManager("mypackage")
plugin.add_hookspecs(PluginSpec)
plugin.load_setuptools_entrypoints("mypackage")
plugin.register(localplugins)
```

The hookspec's need to be static class methods:

```py
from typing import Any
import pluggy


hookspec = pluggy.HookspecMarker("mypackage")


class PluginSpec:
    @staticmethod
    @hookspec
    def plugin_func(*args: Any) -> None:
        ...
```